# Azure Premium Storage - azure storage blob upload both block and page blobs fail

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine, storage

I'm attempting the daunting task of using Azure as a hosting platform(Do not recommend, use AWS for production).

Since the platform has NO BACKUP SOLUTION for premium storage based VMs, I am attempting to backup the files in a more manual method by copying them to blob storage.

azure storage blob upload (key/file/container blah blah)
error:   Block blobs are not supported.

Oh.. Ok, hey if premium storage requires page blobs I'll just use them(oh yeah btw we wont tell you at all how to do any of this btw)!
azure storage blob upload --blobtype page (key/file/container blah blah)
error:   Page blob length must be multiple of 512.

What!? You mean I need to know the exact length of every file I upload? Wow Azure you sure are great!

I realize I can just use standard storage but I find this very annoying.

Oh yeah and for anyone out there in need this is one solution I used that works if you are offloading to standard storage:
The yes n | will automatically say no to every request to overwrite an existing blob with the same name, if your files change you would remove the n and have it overwrite each time.  You will need to install azure cli(linux) and setup credentials for it.

```
#!/bin/bash
yes n |for i in $(find /data/directoryiwanttobackup/ -type f -name '*');          do echo $i; azure storage blob upload -a storageaccount -k "storageaccountkey" $i --container containername $i; done >> /var/log/mybackuplog$(date +"%m%d%Y").log
```

Comment: From what I understand you're trying to backup the contents of a "Premium" storage account to another. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes they are actually the same account, the vhd lives inside the premium storage account, I made another container call it "backups" inside that account.  My assumption was that the file transfers would be faster that way.

Comment: Unless you plan on creating VMs using the backups, I will not actually recommend using a "Premium" storage account for backups. Not only it is not intended use of these kind of storage accounts but also it is extremely pricey (I have been burnt badly because I did not understand the pricing model of a Premium storage account correctly).

Comment: Agreed, I was thinking the same thing.